# Is there way to use angular directives(*ngfor) in angular reactive forms?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, ngfor

When submitting the form, is there a way to retain all the data without replacing with a same data(marks) in the Angular Reactive forms that change with Angular Directives?
I tried bellow code but, I couldn't find out way to get all "marks" inputs.

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of stuData">
      <label>{{item.name}}</label>
      <input type="number" min="0" max="100" placeholder="Marks" formControlName="marks">
    </div>
```

Comment: You question needs some more clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably arrange something with dynamics form groups like this:

https://www.bitovi.com/blog/managing-nested-and-dynamic-forms-in-angular

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let userFormGroup of usersForm.controls.users.controls; let i = index">
  <div [formGroup]="userFormGroup">
    {{stuData[i]}}
     <label>
      Mark
      <input type="text" formControlName="marks">
    </label>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

And in the .ts

```
let fgArray: FormGroup[];

fgArray.forEach(element => {
  this.fb.group({
    mark: ['', null],
  });
})

this.usersForm = this.fb.group({
      users: this.fb.array(fgArray)
})
```